# Induced action from $SL$ to $\mathfrak sl$

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Suppose $SL(V, \mathbb C)$ acts on $V$ as expected, and thus on $V \otimes (V\wedge V)$ as $g \cdot [ v \otimes (w \wedge z)] = g \cdot v \otimes (g \cdot w \wedge g \cdot z )$. Which is the induced action of $\mathfrak sl_n$ on this same spaces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The action of $\mathfrak{sl}(V)$ on $V^{\otimes n}$ is given by $$g\cdot (v_1\otimes \dots\otimes v_n)=gv_1\otimes v_2\otimes\dots \otimes v_n+\dots+ v_1 \otimes \dots  \otimes v_{n-1}\otimes gv_n;$$
and hence the action on its quotients modules (such as $V^{\otimes (n-k)}\otimes\Lambda^k V$) has the same form.

It's obvious from differentiation of the group action (to get at least in a non-rigorous "physicist" way the formula, start from the group action $x\cdot v$, and then compute $(1+g)\cdot v-v$ where $g$ is thought to be infinitesimal and remove terms where $g$ appears at least twice).

Comment: Another, even less rigorous way to see it is to differentiate $g\otimes g$ "noncommutatively" to get $g\otimes 1 + 1\otimes g$ then iterate this for higher tensor powers.

Comment: Thinking twice, this argument is rigorous, say working with $\mathrm{GL}(V)$ and $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$: one indeed has $(1+g)\bullet v=v+g\circ v+ o(\|g\|)$ (for fixed $v$, where $\bullet$ is the group action and $\circ$ is the Lie algebra action).